# How can I adjust a box-shadow at points along an edge?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In Material Design, shadows are intelligently applied based on their height. How can I emulate this?

Example: A toolbar with a 6px shadow overlaps a card with a 4px shadow. The shadow should only be 2px on top of the card, but 6px everywhere else.

JavaScript solutions are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would like to point out that in most cases, the shadow should be below the card but not on top, this is to give a sense of elevation.

Guidelines related to shadows in material design could be found [HERE](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-shadows).

To create an "imbalanced" shadow, you could do this:

```
box-shadow: H V B S C;
```

Where H: horizontal offset, V: vertical offset, B: blur, S: spread, C: color

For example:

```css
div {
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
```

A more "realistic" and advanced example could be found in [w3schools's website](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_box-shadow4). It uses multiple shadows together: `box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);`

Comment: I was talking specifically about an element overlapping an element, and only being smaller for part of an edge.